# 'webbrowser.documentCompleted += procedure' translation from c# to vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, code-translation

Usually when i need to convert code from c# to vb.net i use this link
http://converter.telerik.com/
but looking to an old answer ([WebBrowser Control in a new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269800/webbrowser-control-in-a-new-thread/19718530#19718530))

i found this line that i don't understand, and that the converter don't translate:

br.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;

```
private void runBrowserThread(Uri url) {
var th = new Thread(() => {
    var br = new WebBrowser();
    br.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
    br.Navigate(url);
    Application.Run();
});
th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
th.Start();
}

void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
    var br = sender as WebBrowser;
    if (br.Url == e.Url) {
        Console.WriteLine("Natigated to {0}", e.Url);
        Application.ExitThread();   // Stops the thread
    }
}
```

Anyone know the translation?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not a VB guru, but if it helps - that line is wiring up an event handler.  It's setting browser_DocumentCompleted() to be the event handler for the DocumentCompleted event.

Comment: Thanks, yes, it's an eventHandler, but i don't understand the code, as i know in vb.net isn't possible to sum an eventHandler to a procedure, and i want to understand what the c# code mean

Comment: It's just the C# syntax for adding the handler. += is shorthand for increment by some value.  So you can say x+=1 instead of x = x + 1.  It's also used in the case for the wireup.

Comment: `+=` is used for many things. You can increment as squillman has shown or you can append one string to another, or add an event handler as shown in your example

Answer (score 1):

That line is adding an event handler for `WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted` event, pointing to the `browser_DocumentCompleted` method.

This is the translation:
`AddHandler br.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf browser_DocumentCompleted`

Comment: thank you very much for the quickly reply, but when i meet ' br.DocumentCompleted -= browser_DocumentCompleted;' (note the - instead +)  what it means? thanks

Comment: @Marcello That's the RemoveHandler syntax. It would translate to `RemoveHandler br.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf browser_DocumentCompleted`.